# Read Local Text File function not return string type but a void type

Tags: javascript

i'm learning JavaScript recently and found this problem, my readTextFile function here:

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                // alert(allText);
                return allText;
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

And my onload function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var fileUrl = "input.txt";
    var text =  "";
    text = String(readTextFile(fileUrl));
    window.alert(text);
};
```

The output is "undifined". My "input.txt" file is in the same directory with js file. Please help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`readTextFile` method has an asynchronous ajax call which has a callback handler `onreadystatechange` which will not be invoked in an sequential manner.

this method readTextFile is not returning any value outside this callback method, so you are getting undefined here `text = String(readTextFile(fileUrl));`

you need to alert the response values then and there in the `onreadystatechange`  callback method.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```